# How to show flatlist last part first?

Tags: css, firebase, react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist

I develop a chatting app. I have to show the last chatting message first to customer when they select chatting. I use `scrollToEnd` like this:

```
this.flatListRef.current.scrollToEnd({animated:false});
```

But it shows scrolling down motion. When they enter the chatting room, I don't want to show a scroll motion. How to show flatlist last part first using React native?

I use firestore, React native.

This is video about the problem: https://youtu.be/X2XdbOZI21s

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the props `inverted` of `FlatList`

```
<Flatlist 
  ref={flatListRef} 
  inverted 
  data={messages} 
  renderItem={renderItem} 
/>
```

info : https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#inverted

Answer (score 0):

When I had to implement something similar (a chat also), I just [reversed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) the array put inside the `data` prop of `FlatList`. Meaning that you won't have to scroll to the "last" item, because your last item in your list, will be displayed first.
Let's say your data array is called `messages = [...]`, in your `FlatList` just put it `data={messages.reverse()}` and see what's the behaviour like.

Also, by doing so and avoiding to scroll to the last item, it will be more efficient considering the fact that there can be many messages

Comment: then how to slove date thing? If the date changes while entering the chat, the date is unfolded so that the date is displayed in the center. Developing in the same way as above will cause the following problems.

Comment: That date belongs to an item from your FlatList or how do you display it?

Comment: yes in flatlist that is appears when the creation date is different from the previous message.

Comment: And how exactly should it look & behave like? I mean, I tried to understand what you want to achieve, but it's a bit confusing. If you could share a bit more info, I'll be able to understand

Comment: i add image it must be at the top of messages of the same date